# How to get and set a C structure in Redis with Drogon Web Framework?

Tags: c++, redis

My goal is to create an REST service with Drogon C++ server that is able to get and set a C structure in and from Redis.
I have done some test with Hiredis and it is working well. But not within Drogonweb server.

For my test ,I am using the following C structure :

```
typedef struct mytest {
    int myInt;
    long myLong;
    long myLong1;
    long myLong2;
    long myLong3;
    long myLong4;
    long myLong5;
    long myLong6;
    long myLong7;
    long myLong8;
    long myLong9;
    long myLong10;
    long myLong11;
    long myLong12;
    long myLong13;
    long myLong14;
    long myLong15;
    long myLong16;
    long myLong17;
    long myLong18;
    long myLong19;
    long myLong20;
    long myLong21;
    long myLong22;
    long myLong23;
    long myLong24;
    long myLong25;
    long myLong26;
    long myLong27;
    long myLong28;
    long myLong29;
    long myLong30;
    long myLong31;


} mytest;
```

Here my Drogon code for handling the POST request and set a structure in Redis :

```
void Client::post(const HttpRequestPtr& req,
    std::function<void(const HttpResponsePtr&)>&& callback,
    std::string key)
{

    nosql::RedisClientPtr redisClient = app().getRedisClient();
    auto json = req->getJsonObject();

    if (!json)
    {
        auto resp = HttpResponse::newHttpResponse();
        resp->setBody("missing 'value' in body");
        resp->setStatusCode(k400BadRequest);
        callback(resp);
        return;
    }

    std::string value = (*json)["value"].asString();


    mytest t;
    t.myInt = 5; 
    t.myLong = 123451; 
    t.myLong31 = 58;


    redisClient->execCommandAsync
    (
        [callback](const nosql::RedisResult& r) {
            auto resp = HttpResponse::newHttpResponse();

            resp->setStatusCode(k201Created);

            callback(resp);
        },
        [](const std::exception& err) {
            LOG_ERROR << "something failed!!! " << err.what();
        },
            "set %s %s",
            key.c_str(),
            &t 
   );

}
```

Problem : this call isonly appending in Redis a 1 byte value when I was expecting to get my full structure saved in redis memory. Is there anyway to do that with Drogon, or should I try to use hiredis directly ?

Comment: You may want to consider using a higher-level library with support for serialization of your own data types like Aedis https://mzimbres.github.io/aedis/

Answer (score 0):

- You need to serialize `mytest` to string, before setting it to Redis.
- Also if the serialized string is not binary-safe, you need to use *%b*, instead of *%s* when formatting it.